# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException error on splashscreen.java

Tags: java, android, eclipse, stack-trace

I keep getting this errors related to Thread.stop() in splashscreen.java. I'm pretty new at it and aware of deprecated Thread.stop() but can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong here, thanks..

```
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1076)
    at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1063)
    at com.dapp.d.SplashScreen$4.run(SplashScreen.java:88)
```

This is full source code of splashscreen.java

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

    public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

private boolean active = true;
private int splashTime = 3000;
private boolean clickFlag = true;
private Thread splashTread = null;
private Button btnHelp;
private Button btnAboutUs;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.splashRelativeLayout);
    relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.exmaple.com");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

     btnAboutUs = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAboutus);
     btnHelp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnHelp);

    try{

        btnAboutUs.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                clickFlag = false;
                splashTread.stop();  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< line 49
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), AboutUs.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                SplashScreen.this.finish();
            }
        });

        btnHelp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                clickFlag = false;
                splashTread.stop();   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< line 63
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), HelpActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                SplashScreen.this.finish();
            }
        });

        splashTread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try{
                    int waited = 0;
                    while(active && (waited < splashTime)) {
                        sleep(100);
                        waited += 100;
                    }                       
                } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                    // do nothing
                }finally {
                    if(clickFlag){
                        Intent intent=new Intent();
                        intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), SearchWord.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                        stop(); <<<<<<<<<<<<<<< line 88
                    }else{
                        finish();
                        stop();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        splashTread.start();

    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}

    }
```

Comment: run the application removing after stop()

Comment: That caused it to forceclose on all versions whereas before it didn't..

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to call stop there at all.  Your thread doesn't loop so it will execute and end normally.  Try just removing the stop();

Comment: and if that still doesn't do the trick, try joining them instead. in fact, comment everything below startActivity().

Comment: I removed stop() but it still forceclosed the app. Removing line 49 and 63 - same results, any better ideas? thanks.

Comment: Im not familiar with a Thread.finish() is that your method?  also when you catch the exception you should at least log the exception because currently an exception may be being caught and you are unaware of it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and the solution is to wrap the stop method in a try/catch statment and in the catch use Throwable t.
It will work.